# How to deal with 128bit variable in MinGW32 bit compiler on Qt?

Tags: qt, c++, programming, libraries, boost

I want to use the below equation in one of the code

### A = g^a mod p; //g raise to a modulus p.

(something like 2^5 % 3) = 32%3 = 2

(This equation looks like Diffie Hellman algorithm for security)

Where,

^ is (power)

g is fixed number 0x05

a is 128bit(16bytes) randomly generated number,

and p is fixed hex number of 128bit(16bytes)

something like (0x0xD4A283974897234CE908B3478387A3).

I am using,

Qt 4.8.7

Compiler MinGW32

(checked with boost library boost 1.70)

### The solutions which I found which didn`t work for me are listed below:

1 one can use __int128 but to support that one should have used
latest GCC compiler or MinGW64 bit compiler, neither of that I am using now.

2 I found one latest version of Qt has QSslDiffieHellmanParameters class,
but again not supported in our Qt version.

3 I found some libraries like  boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp (boost 1.70))
that does have data type such as int128_t and int256_t, but due to 
our compiler isssue or something else, we are not able to store
128bit number, meaning
if i do,

```
int128_t ptval128 = 0xAB1232423243434343BAE3453345E34B;
cout << "ptval128 = " << std::hex << ptval128 << endl;
//will print only 0xAB12324232434343;//half digits only,
```

4 I tried using Bigint which much more useful, but again
5^(128bit number) is way too big, it takes hours to compute things,
(I waited till 1 hour  and 16 mins and kill the application).

```
int myGval = 0x05;
128_bit_data_type myPVal= 0xD4A283974897234CE908B3478387A3; 

128_bit_data_type 128_bit_variable = 128_bit_random_data;
myVal = (myGval)^(128_bit_variable) % (myPVal);
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer here ask on our sister site Stack Overflow that focuses on programming questions.

Comment: It might also be helpful to clarify what MinGW32 compiler you are using exactly since as per your point (1) the Ubuntu/Debian multiarch `w64-mingw32-gcc-win32` does appear to provide 128-bit types (although I'm not sure that an overloaded C++ `<<` operator is implemented for them)

Comment: @steeldriver, __int128 is there, but it can`t hold that much long value, and yes, either << operator has to be overloaded or function has to be made to print value, somewhat similar issue mentioned in point (3).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, Thank you for your suggestion, I already asked this question there and got an answer.

Comment: @RohitDharaviya Glad they could answer the question. I'm voting to close the same question here off-topic.